# Help with nuances of a list please? X や Y も..."X and Y, as well" or "X as well as Y"?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, nuances, particles

I'm just double-checking the nuances of a translation. The speaker is listing several people here:

> オレやひろしも藤岡さん【ふじおかさん】やお前【おまえ】の両親【りょうしん】だって黙まってねえ

Contextually, the speaker, listener and Hiroshi are a group of three close friends. The presence of the も is kind of confusing me on whether the speaker's saying "I, as well as Hiroshi," or "Hiroshi and me, as well".

Basically, like the subject header said: "X and Y, as well" or "X as well as Y"?

I mean, is the speaker using the も to add Hiroshi to the list?

> "I, and Hiroshi too, Fujioka-san and even your parents, we won't stay quiet."

Or is the speaker using the も to add himself *and* Hiroshi to the list?

> "I and Hiroshi, as well as Fujioka-san and even your parents, we won't stay quiet."

I'm assuming it's the second one, both because of the context and the や there.

I mean, if the speaker had wanted to treat himself and Hiroshi as separate incidents using も, then he'd have said "オレもひろしも" right? "I, as well as Hiroshi,"

But, instead he used "オレやひろしも" which leads me to believe the speaker is treating himself and Hiroshi as one item with the や and then linking them to the rest of the list with the も "Hiroshi and me, as well as etc."

Anyway, some confirmation would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translations are always a little funny because they are always influenced by the listeners own understood nuances.

I would translate this as

```
Hiroshi and I, even Fujioka and your parents, aren't staying quiet.
```

The も in this case, separates the two groups of "Hiroshi and I" and "Fujioka and your parents" which is why I put the "even" before "Fujioka"

Finally, the verb form at the end sounds more like people are already saying things...

Comment: ahhh, separating them into two groups does make sense!! I'm sorry about the odd verb at the end, I had to cp this from a longer sentence talking about a hyporthetical situation.